# Watershed Algorithm with manual markers in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, watershed

I want to apply watershed algorithm to an image with predefined markers using Opencv package. I have a original image for example "coffee_grains.jpg" and a marker image "coffee_markers.png". I simply applied watershed algorithm on image and its marker, similar to OpenCV documentation but I got simply a result similar to labels.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
work_dir = './'
coffi = cv.imread(work_dir+'TestImages/coffee_grains.jpg')
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(coffi)
labels = cv.imread(work_dir+'TestImages/coffee_markers.png')
labels = cv.cvtColor(labels ,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(labels)
labels = labels.astype(np.int32)
labels = cv.watershed(coffi,labels)
plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(labels)
plt.show()
```

And here is resulting images:
[image: coffee grains watershed]

Am I doing something wrong?!

Comment: if you have the markers, just apply `connectedComponents`

Comment: You need the markers to be foreground color (255 in OpenCV) and the background 0. Then you need to label that image, and then you can use it as seeds in the watershed. Follow the tutorial more closely: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html